# Shell Script CentOS - Killing process by reading it's config file and getting the port

Tags: linux, shell, centos, sh, lsof

I am looping through folders with Java applications and getting the config file for each.

> app1/config.yml
>
> app2/config.yml
>
> etc.

I then pull the port from this config file by using:

`port= cat app1/config.yml  | grep 90 | cut -d: -f2`

I want to use the port to kill the application, I did find this code that does half of what I want it to do:

```
kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:4990)
```

I want to use the variable stored in port to execute the kill command, but I can't get it to work, what is the correct way to use the command, I have tried multiple ways:

```
kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:$port)
kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:port)
kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:"$port")
kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:'$port')
```

But none of these work, I keep getting errors.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The first and third should both have worked. Why would you expect the last to work, don't you know the difference between single and doule quotes in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

You're not setting `port` correctly, you left out the `$(...)` around the command.

```
port=$(cat app1/config.yml  | grep 90 | cut -d: -f2)
kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:$port)
```